# How to copy all text and exe files in a folder [windows]

Tags: windows

Is there any way to copy all `.text` and `exe` files in folder?

like,

```
cp *.[exe|txt] c:\temp
```

Comment: Not really @and31415

Comment: Here's the code from the second link: `for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" D:\pictures` It does what you want, you just need to replace `*.jpg` with `*.exe;*.txt` and adjust the source/target folders, as needed.

Comment: `copy *.?x? c:\temp`

Comment: @techie007 That would copy *any* file with a three-letter extension whose second character is a `x`.

Comment: @and31415 I'm well aware. it's just a specific suggestion to a specific scenario. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [RoboCopy](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm) (Robust File Copy), it comes pre-installed on Windows Vista, 7 and more (on the link):

`robocopy "source" "target" *.exe *.txt /S`

The `/S` means `Copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.`

If you want to find all the commands on RoboCopy, type this in at cmd: `robocopy /???`

Comment: I want one liner command.

Comment: look into robocopy, it comes with windows 7

Comment: @Gynac Edited to use robocopy

Comment: `You don't need to use cmd, on Windows 7` Presumptuous!